# Android Studio showing id conflict with deleted elements

Tags: android, android-studio

I've had an old EditText element in my app xml file which I deleted and I've added a new material design TextInputLayout element.

when I try to build the app I get an error of id conflict between the new existing element and the old deleted one.

this is the exisiting element:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cost_of_service"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/cost_of_service_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and the error message I get:

> <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout id='@+id/cost_of_service'> conflicts with another tag that has the same ID

while there is no other element with that id.

!!! even if I try to switch the existing element id, the error stays the same.
it's like android studio is unaware of the changes I make.

Comment: Clean -> Rebuild -> Invalidate & Restart.

Comment: done clean -> rebuild, still rebuild fails with same error

Comment: File - Invalidate & Restart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...

This will clear the cache and solve your problem.